# This is often vs This often is

Tags: adverbs, word-order, syntax, adverb-placement

Is it correct to write

> This often is done for something.

rather than

> This is often done for something.

Comment: Sure, [take a look](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+often+is%2Cthis+is+often&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). The latter is far more common, but that doesn't make the alternative "incorrect".

Comment: The first one is extremely awkward unless there is a reason to use it as in academic writing. often often precedes happen or occur, but not the verb to be: This often occurs [when].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought that the variant *"This is often done for something"* sounds more grammatically correct.

Because the adverbs of frequency have to precede the main verb. Actually the adverb is put before the word it's modifying.

But your alternative variant *"This often is done for something"* definitely make sense, though it sounds a bit as a colloquial expression.